# How are the product xml files and the pcf files connected in Policycenter?

Tags: guidewire

When we create a product, few xml files are generated for the product, its offerings etc. How is the data from these xml's read into the pcf file?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct connection between the product model xml files, and the PCF files.  The product model is used to tell the PolicyCenter back end all the information about your products, the availability of these, allowed values for coverage terms, questions etc...

The PCF files are just your views for PolicyCenter, they determine what html is generated for the front end.  They will indirectly access the data in the xml to determine whether a given offering, coverage, line etc... is available, and its default state, and certain validations.